# Data not rendering in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

Controller:

```
public with sharing class Opportunity_DAQuoteCtrlExt {

private final Opportunity rhOppty;
Opportunity thisOppty = new Opportunity(); 


public Opportunity_DAQuoteCtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.rhOppty = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    }

public List<Design_Atelier_Quote__c> daQuoteList{
    get{
        if(daQuoteList == null){     

                System.debug('Oppty Id: ' + this.rhOppty.Id);       

                thisOppty = [SELECT Id, Oppty_Number__c FROM Opportunity where Id = :this.rhOppty.Id]; 

                System.debug('Oppty Number: ' + thisOppty.Oppty_Number__c);              

                List<Design_Atelier_Quote__c> daQuoteList = [SELECT EXT_Oppty_Number__c, Quote_Id__c, Forecast__c, Order_Subtotal__c, Quote_Forecast_Amount__c from Design_Atelier_Quote__c WHERE EXT_Oppty_Number__c =:thisOppty.Oppty_Number__c];

            }               
        return daQuoteList;
        }
    set;        
   }
}
```

daQuoteList returns:

```
{EXT_Oppty_Number__c=Z160523-146681, Quote_Id__c=qU0T31d1,Forecast__c=true, Order_Subtotal__c=100000.00, Quote_Forecast_Amount__c=100000.00, Id=a1rQ0000001hbPAIAY, CurrencyIsoCode=USD}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Opportunity_DAQuoteCtrlExt">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="detail">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!daQuoteList}" var="daQuote">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Quote" value="{!daQuote.Quote_Id__c}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Subtotal" value="{!daQuote.Order_Subtotal__c}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Forecast" value="{!daQuote.Forecast__c}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>   
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Result: the table renders with the column headers but no data. What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the query results to a local variable not the property of the same name:

```
List<Design_Atelier_Quote__c> daQuoteList = [SELECT ...];
```

Removing the type part will stop the line being a new declaration and just make it an assignment to the existing property:

```
daQuoteList = [SELECT ...];
```